# C++ Type Erasure for function parameters

Tags: c++, type-erasure

So in Java we have generics, whereby I'm looking to achieve something similar to the following in C++

```
public interface ListenerIF <T> {
    public void onChange(T eventData);
}

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ListenerIF<String>> foo = ...;
    List<ListenerIF<Integer>> bar = ...;
    foo.add((strUpdate) -> {/*some string operation*/});
    bar.add((intUpdate) -> {/*some math*/});
    foo.forEach((listener) -> listener.onChange("some change"));
    bar.forEach((listener) -> listener.onChange(123));
}
```

But with C++ templates fundamentally being different (and needing all implementations up front), I'm trying to understand how to accomplish something similar in C++ using type erasure (and since the JVM is written in C++, I'm quite certain it's possible and just eluding me).

I can get type erasure where I want it in terms of `ListenerIF`, but I can't figure out how to make type `T` dynamic for the function `ListenerIF::onChange(T)`. This is what I've arrived at for getting ListenerIF working (without T being dynamic, and here just as std::string):

```
class ListenerIF {
  public:
    //how do I get the parameter to this function to be dynamic?
    virtual void onChange(std::string) = 0;
};

template<typename LISTENER>
class Listener: public ListenerIF {
  public:
    //how do I get the parameter to this function to be dynamic?
    void onChange(std::string update) {
      l.onChange(update);
  private:
    LISTENER l;
};

class Foo {
  public:
    //how do I get the parameter to this function to be dynamic?
    void onChange(std::string);
};
class Bar {
  public:
    //how do I get the parameter to this function to be dynamic?
    void onChange(std::string);
};

void Foo::onChange(std::string update){}
void Bar::onChange(std::string update){}

int main() {
  std::vector<ListenerIF *> listeners;
  listeners.push_back(new Listener<Foo>());
  listeners.push_back(new Listener<Bar>());
  for(std::vector<ListenerIF *>::iterator listenersItr = listeners.begin(); listenersItr < listeners.end(); listenersItr++){
    (*listenersItr)->onChange("some string update");
}
```

Which is all fine if I just want to 'onChange' to just be for strings, but if I want to have a completely different 'onChange' type to be an int, float, or some other object type then this breaks down.

Am I just not understanding something simple that I've left out?

Comment: Side note: write `listenersItr == listeners.end()`, not `listenersItr < listeners.end()` (iterators are == comparable, but not necessarily < comparable). And write `++listenersItr`, not `listenersItr++`, this does not require a temporary.

Comment: This is more psudeo code than code. I'm transcribing from a different workstation that is not plugged into the internet.

Comment: You did already post the correct keyword here as tag: type-erasure. Assuming you work with pointers (which is pretty similar to java references) you can use type that every pointer type can be converted to: `void*` which would allow you do `virtual void onChange(void*) = 0;` and `void Foo::onChange(void* update){ const std::string* str = dynamic_cast<const std::string*>(update); if (str == nullptr) throw ClassCastException; ... delete str;/* not sure this is the correct place to free the memory */ }`, but I'd consider the quality of this code pretty low...

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is not erased in the Java version (`ListenerIF<T>`).

The equivalent C++ would also **keep** the parameter:

```
template <typename T> // <- need a template parameter
class listener_interface {
public:
    virtual void on_change(const T& data) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the template to `ListenerIF` itself, just like the Java code does, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class ListenerIF {
public:
    virtual ~ListenerIF() {};
    virtual void onChange(const T &eventData) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
using listenerIF_ptr = std::unique_ptr<ListenerIF<T>>;

...

class FooListener : public ListenerIF<std::string> {
public:
    void onChange(const std::string &eventData) override {
        /* some string operation */
    }
};

class BarListener : public ListenerIF<int> {
public:
    void onChange(const int &eventData) override {
        /* some math */
    }
};

...

int main() {
    std::vector<ListenerIF_ptr<std::string>> foo;
    std::vector<ListenerIF_ptr<int>> bar;

    foo.push_back(std::make_unique<FooListener>());
    bar.push_back(std::make_unique<BarListener>());

    for(auto &listener : foo) { listener->onChange("some change"); }
    for(auto &listener : bar) { listener->onChange(123); }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/uYljQW)

However, in this situation, I would suggest using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (or even a plain function pointer) with [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), instead of using polymorphic interface types, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
using listenerIF = std::function<void(const T&)>;
// or: listenerIF = void(*)(const T&);

int main() {
    std::vector<listenerIF<std::string>> foo;
    std::vector<listenerIF<int>> bar;

    foo.push_back(
        [](const std::string &eventData){
            /* some string operation */
        }
    );
    bar.push_back(
        [](const int &eventData) {
            /* some math */
        }
    );

    for(auto &listener : foo) { listener("some change"); }
    for(auto &listener : bar) { listener(123); }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/nBa4fR)